# Typing over selected text replaces some text to the right

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

In OS X (both Lion and Mountain Lion), I notice that when I select text and type over it, not only does it yield the expected result of replacing that text with the typed text, it often also replaces a few characters to the right. When that happens, I notice that after the first few keystrokes, some text remains selected.

Comment: So what is the question? This happens because the autocorrection system lags behind your typing speed, mainly due to a slow computer.

Comment: It's a correctness issue, not a performance issue. If it was a lag issue, that can't explain character I type appearing on the screen while the remaining highlighted character stay highlighted and additional characters to the right also become highlighted as a result of typing.

Comment: That’s exactly what happened on my old Mac. It was solved by a reinstall, and a clean reinstall at that. And trust me, it’s a performance issue. I have found it mainly occurs while using Safari, though I don’t know if that’s because Safari is what I use the most.

Comment: It's not a performance issue if the actual result of doing something is **incorrect** as opposed to just being slow. As a programmer, I'm aware of the possibility of slowness revealing an otherwise latent bug caused by a race condition. In such cases, performance isn't the prbblem; It merely reveals the problem. A reinstall won't help as I've had this problem on my mid-2011 MacBook Air since I bought it brand new.

Comment: I've had this issue on my mba since I bought it about a month ago. Autocorrect is disabled.

Comment: In which applications? And could there be any relation to text encoding (unicode chars)?

Comment: This is not a performance issue. My M2 Macbook Air is doing this and I've only had it a couple of days. I encourage others to report this bug to Apple.